# Kivy- Aidl cannot be exectuted even after installing 32bit libs

Tags: android, python, kivy, aidl, buildozer

Im new to kivy. When im trying to build my app for android using buildozer, i get the following error

```
# Check that aidl can be executed
# Search for Aidl
# Run '/home/khishorebsk/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/0/aidl'
# Cwd None
# Aidl cannot be executed
# 
# You might have missed to install 32bits libs
# Check http://buildozer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html
# 
# Check configuration tokens
#
```

Ive tried installing 32 libs using the following commands

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cython==0.21
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential ccache git libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 python2.7 python2.7-dev openjdk-8-jdk unzip zlib1g-dev zlib1g:i386
```

But still im getting the same error. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you first need to get a detailed info about what's going on:
Go to your `Android Sdk` directory, e.g.:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2
```

Try executing `aidl`:

```
./aidl --help
```

You will receive a detailed error message which will help you to fix the issue.
In my particular case the error message was following:

```
aidl: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/clang_9.0.0/lib/libc++.so: file too short
```

That is because I had `/usr/local/clang_9.0.0` added to PATH in file `~/.bashrc`. After removing it the problem disappeared.